# Is there any way to use an "or" operator in Google Directory API users.list query?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I want to build a search query for Google domain users using **users.list** *Google Directory API*. I tried to build a query according [docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users), which will select all users with *givenName* **or** *familyName* starts e.g. on letter "m".
I wrote the query: 
`givenName:m* or familyName:m*`, but it doesn't work.
Only `givenName:m* familyName:m*` works but it inserts "and" operator between clauses.
In docs stays:

> Multiple clauses are separated by whitespace and are implicitly joined by an "and" operator.

Can I only write a query with the implicit "and" operator? Is there any way how to write it using **"or"**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time experimenting with the [API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) I have found out that I really don't need **{{PREFIX}}*** or some operators to accomplish my goal.

If you want to search all the users whose given or family name starts e.g. on letter "m", just put a single `m` (without field name e.g. "givenName:") into the query parameter. It seems that API implicitly searches in all domain users' *givenName* and *familyName* fields. It also searches in a substring (before "@") of all email fields (e.g. **martin**@example.com).

If you put word "example" in the query, it'll gives you all users with email field something@**example**.com.

It is possible that if you put only some string without any specified fields, the API may also searches in any other field, but I didn't find in which.

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, but I know it partially gives an answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use uppercase:

```
givenName:m* OR familyName:m*
```

Comment: You are right, it is not working. But my point is the use of "OR" vs "or" (invalid). You can edit your question to correct it and avoid more misunderstandings.