# Google Admin Directory API: how to OR query terms?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to query my organization's Directory for users, in a case where I need to match multiple possible incoming familyName and givenName combos.  So for instance, I know a user has possible givenName Will or Bill, and possible familyName Gates or Gates Jr.

It seems like one of these queries should work, but nothing so far has been successful

`(familyName=Gates OR familyName='Gates Jr') (givenName=Will OR givenName=Bill)
familyName=[Gates|'Gates Jr'] givenName=[Will|Bill]
(familyName=Gates || familyName='Gates Jr') && (givenName=Will || givenName=Bill)`

etc

Is OR for some reason just not possible, or am I missing something silly?

Comment: Even I tried to retrieve users with familyName:A* OR familyName:D*, but it didnt work for me too. Also, || operator is working as AND operator. But I found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732368/is-there-any-way-to-use-an-or-operator-in-google-directory-api-users-list-quer for workaround.

Comment: I found that question as well, but its really only a "workaround" in the very specific case of that question, ie when you want to query in both first and last name, you can just query name: instead.  That's... or... ish?  Unfortunately, not a help in my case.